# Dplyr mutate new column at a specified location

Tags: r, dplyr

An example:

```
a = c(10,20,30)
b = c(1,2,3)
c = c(4,5,6)
d = c(7,8,9)
df=data.frame(a,b,c,d)

library(dplyr)

df_1 = df %>% mutate(a1=sum(a+1))
```

How do I add "a1" after "a" (or any other defined position) and NOT at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: Accept an answer @ip2018?

Answer (score 51):

An update that might be useful for others who find this question - this can now be achieved directly within `mutate` (I'm using `dplyr` v1.0.2).

Just specify which existing column the new column should be positioned after or before, e.g.:

```
df_after <- df %>% 
   mutate(a1=sum(a+1), .after = a)

df_before <- df %>% 
   mutate(a1=sum(a+1), .before = b)
```

Answer (score 18):

Another option is `add_column` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)    
add_column(df, a1 = sum(a + 1), .after = "a")
#   a a1 b c d
#1 10 63 1 4 7
#2 20 63 2 5 8
#3 30 63 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 10):

Extending on www's answer, we can use dplyr's `select_helper` functions to reorder newly created columns as we see fit:

```r
library(dplyr)

## add a1 after a
df %>% 
    mutate(a1 = sum(a + 1)) %>%
    select(a, a1, everything())
#>    a a1 b c d
#> 1 10 63 1 4 7
#> 2 20 63 2 5 8
#> 3 30 63 3 6 9

## add a1 after c
df %>% 
    mutate(a1 = sum(a + 1)) %>%
    select(1:c, a1, everything())
#>    a b c a1 d
#> 1 10 1 4 63 7
#> 2 20 2 5 63 8
#> 3 30 3 6 63 9
```

Answer (score 4):

**dplyr >= 1.0.0**

[`relocate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html) was added as a new verb to change the order of one or more columns. If you pipe the output of your `mutate` the syntax for `relocate` also uses `.before` and `.after` arguments:

```
df_1 %>% 
  relocate(a1, .after = a)
   a a1 b c d
1 10 63 1 4 7
2 20 63 2 5 8
3 30 63 3 6 9
```

---

An additional benefit is you can also move multiple columns using any [`tidyselect`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) syntax:

```
df_1 %>% 
  relocate(c:a1, .before = b)
   a c d a1 b
1 10 4 7 63 1
2 20 5 8 63 2
3 30 6 9 63 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `mutate` function will always add the newly created column at the end. However, we can sort the column alphabetically after the `mutate` function using `select`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(a1 = sum(a + 1)) %>%
  select(sort(names(.)))
df_1
#    a a1 b c d
# 1 10 63 1 4 7
# 2 20 63 2 5 8
# 3 30 63 3 6 9
```

Comment: Actually, the column names are random and does not necessarily contain alphabetical information to be used for sorting. My use of a,b,c etc might have lead to the confusion. Sorry.

Comment: It is OK. Then I think the answer provided by @akrun is the one you need.